# Post Form to a page in CQ5

Tags: search, post, aem

I have a custom search component which searches for some parameter(s) from a dropdown `[myParam]` and displays the search results in another page. I currently use the default (GET) form

```
<form id="searchForm" action="/content/myWeb/searchResult.html" method="get" target="_blank">
```

In the result page, a component picks up the request params and processes the search.

I need to make it a POST submission so that the search parameters are NOT visible in the URL.  But if I make it a `method="Post"` in the form above, I get this error:

```
Status  
500
Message     
javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: no matching property definition found for {}myParam
Location    /content/myWeb/searchResult
Parent Location     /content/myWeb
Path    
/path/to/search/page
```

Answer (score 4):

That exception is the incidental way that Sling tells you that the servlet to which you are attempting to POST can not be found. What happens, in this case, is that Sling defaults to the SlingDefaultPostServlet, which attempts to to POST properties (represented by your form values) to the node /content/myWeb/searchResult. There's no way for Sling to say "I can't find a servlet that's registered to your request", so it just falls back to it's default behavior.

I'm assuming /content/myWeb/searchResult is a cq:Page node type. That node type is very restrictive, which is why it tells you that you cannot add properties that correspond to your form values.

This worked before, because your GET request to /content/myWeb/searchResult.html was able to resolve and execute. All GET requests to a page node can be served up by the system, inherently.

Now, since you are trying to do a POST, you need to create and register a new servlet that can handle this POST request. To do this, you'll need to create a [SlingPostServlet](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html) and register it to your specific path (not recommended) or a specific selector/extension combination (recommended). That servlet should process the request parameters and respond with an HTML document.

A caveat...

What I just described will help you technically build what you are asking. That said, I don't agree with the premise that you should "make it a POST to hide the request parameters." The reason this is so much extra work, is because you are circumventing the principles of REST, which Sling is theoretically built to support. Your URL (via request path and parameters) should be communicating "I want the page at /content/myWeb/searchResult, given the criteria param1=x, param2=y, and so on". The GET with request params is an appropriately RESTful request.

I suggest you rethink what you're trying to do. Building a more complex solution around RESTful principles is not a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, makes s lot of sense. I was searching for over a day. Can you share any example you may have on the use of SlingPostServlet?

Answer (score 1):

Just as a sidenote, you can always check if a given URL is bound to a servlet via the sling servlet resolver. Reachable via the OSGI-console or via URL:

```
http://localhost:4502/system/console/servletresolver
```

This can at least help you find closure on, if the servlet is registered to the given URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a POST.jsp for your page, which could handle the POST request.

It is not restful to make get like request with POST, but sometimes it can be useful. Also With POST, dispatcher won't cache your request.

Comment: Just on caching, the dispatcher wouldn't cache a `GET` request that has query parameter either.

Comment: yep, query parameters also eliminate caching